# How to use camel type converter to convert exchange data into file object in apahce camel?

Tags: apache, https, apache-camel

Hello I need to send one file and some authentication data over the https server I am using file component for get file in camel exchange.

```
from("file:/home/r2/Desktop/ofBizFile?fileName=someFile")
        .process(new ProcessorSetReq()) 
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY,constant("USERNAME=__&PASSWORD=__"))
        .to("https4://someAddress")
        .to("stream:out");
```

I'm expecting something like this in my processor code

```
public void process(Exchange exchange)throws Exception{
  MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

  File file =new File(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
  builder.addPart("configId",new StringBody("I_ORDER"));
  builder.addPart("EnumId",new StringBody("CSV_FILE"));

  builder.addPart("uploadedFile",new FileBody(file));//There is a problem
  exchange.getIn().setBody(builder.build()); 
}
```

How I can send file in required parameter.There is any other way to do this?

Comment: After adding converter **File file = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
                                   builder.addPart("upload", new FileBody(file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, filename));** This throwing exception which is **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File may not be null** @pvpkiran

Comment: my actual route is from("file:/home/r2/Desktop/ofBizFile")
   .to("https4://getingTokenAddress")
   **.process(new ProcessorSetReq())**
                        .to("https4://someAddressToSend");